# How to Run World of Minecraft on Ubuntu?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, ubuntu, minecraft-classic-browser

I have Downloaded World of Minecraft, (WOM), and have received an `wom.sh` file instead of a jar. I've researched on how to install this but nothing seems to be working. What am I supposed to do? I have the properties marked `Allow Running as an Executable`.

Comment: Have you read and followed the WoM linux tutorial *exactly*? http://www.worldofminecraft.com/tutorials/game_client_linux

Comment: What is "world of Minecraft"? Is that a program, a mod or what? And what does it have to do with Minecraft Classic?

Answer (score 2):

You can execute sh files in a terminal (for example `gnome-terminal`).

To make the file executable (which you already did):

`chmod +x wom.sh`

to run the file:

`./wom.sh`